# How can I check if server is reachable in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to check for a network connection in my app using this code but it always uses the connection unsuccessful code. This is my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: @"example.com/in-app/net.test" ]];
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"internet is working"]){


    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Conection Succesful" message:@"You have succesfully connected to our server. "
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alertsuccess show];
    [alertsuccess release];


} else {
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Unsuccesful" message:@"failed to connect"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertsuccess show];
    [alertsuccess release];  
}

}
```

So again, How can I check if server is reachable in Objective-C? This code *should* work and the server side code works but in the app it does not.

Comment: Did you try logging `serverOutput`?

Comment: Thats what im doing this verry second, ill post results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URLWithString` expects a RFC 2396 conforming URL that includes the scheme (e.g. "http"):

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/in-app/net.test"]
```

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler way of achieving this is using Apple's Reachability class, which uses the SystemConfiguration framework to check if there is an internet connection available.

I would strongly suggest that you have a look at these two links to apple's developer websites.

- [Apple's sample code for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [Framework's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/_index.html)

Comment: Yes, it should only be noted that SCNetworkReachability tests the reachability of a target host, but not that the host is actually running and receives packets.